# Packets being filtered when using NEPacketTunnelProvider

Tags: ios, networking, networkextension

I am using a per-app network extension with NEPacketTunnelProvider, and have noticed when I use a test program that leverages WKWebView I see some URLs are not even coming into readPacketsWithCompletionHandler:

For example, when I try to hit a URL "http://testweb.eng.local" I never see it come in at all. But if I use the IP address, I see it coming in through the handler and see it go through my VPN fine so that I can reach the back end.

Why would "testweb.eng.local" be filtered and how can I control this? If possible I want to have nothing filtered, instead having everything from that app go through the VPN.

UPDATE: Just to clarify, both matchDomains and exceptionList (of NEDNSSettings) are to nil. So I believe everything should be going through.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I discovered there appears to be an issue in iOS where .local is not properly resolved:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6555023?tstart=0